# Is any depth change allowed on electrical panel wall?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance

I know the NEC requires clear space in front of a breaker panel.

What depth of wall change would violate this? My basement, where the panel is, has a 6" jut where the block wall becomes timber. So from where your toes are against the wall, the panel is 6" deeper, as the wall depth changes.

From the side (black line is the floor), it's like this:

[image]

The flush panel is in the framing above. There is also framing below.
All walls are finished properly but because of the construction the panel door is six inches deeper from the edge of the floor.

I am fine with the 30" horizontal clearance.

How should I interpret the clear space requirement in NEC in this situation? Am I required to extend the top half of the wall out to keep it entirely flat and bring the panel out to that the new depth?

Comment: Is this panel *surface* mounted or *flush* mounted?

Comment: It's Flush mounted

Comment: Would changing the panel out for a surface mounted box be an option?

Comment: I'd much rather not because all the existing wire terminations are cut to appropriate length.

Comment: Is there about 14-16" of clear space to either side of the panel?

Comment: Yes. There is 30" clear in both directions. It's in the middle of a long wall.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the existing panel (door open, showing the breakers clearly), by the way?

Comment: If you could tell me what you're looking for it would help me :)

Comment: I'm trying to judge how much wire you'd have to stuff down a conduit to get it over from the old panel location to a new one.  If you could post the make and model of the existing panel, that'd help as well :)

Comment: Is there a reason you want me to explore moving the panel? I like it where it is :)

Comment: you can replace the existing panel with a flush-mount pull box to provide a place to splice wires, then pipe spliced-in wires to an adjacent surface-mounted panel, and that'd get you out of this jam.

Comment: Sure, but I only need to move the panel if it is required.

Comment: I'd move it in this case, but I tend to be a zealot about 110.26(A) as it's one of the most commonly (and irksomely) violated Code sections out there.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. I did read 110.26(A)(3) though and it clearly allows for this case as much as 6". Looks like I'm safe.

Comment: I can see where an AHJ would read the wall kickout as not "associated with the electrical installation" though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEC's clearance requirements are for the safety of people working on equipment once it is installed.

With that being said the NEC width requirement is a minimum of 30", and the door swing if there is one minimum is 90 degrees. However your panel does not have to sit in the center of the 30" it can be moved from side to side.

Reading you question I can't determine whether you panel is against the block wall and the wall depth change is 6" and runs the other direction at that same depth at least 30" or there is just a recess that the panel fits in and it is recessed in an area less than 30". So with the first situation the panel is fine and with the latter, it needs to be brought out to meet clearance.

Also I don't know if you are speaking about a horizontal recess and the panel is mounted below the block wall. Most AHJ will allow 8" before they consider overhead being an interference.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know a 6" gutter is allowed but have not run into a depth of wall issue in the past I believe the biggest offset I have delt with is 12" cement and 6" wall with the panel flush it was only 4" step and my ahj allowed that. I would verify with your inspector .

Comment: I've added a drawing to clarify. The side-to-side clearance is fine as this wall is clear. I'm more asking about the depth from the floor. For example, I wouldn't be able to add a counter or lower cabinetry below the panel.

Comment: @Matthew - When it comes to depth the NEC states that there shall be no obstruction greater than 6" (NEC Article 110.26 (A) (3) ), but there is an Exception No. 2 which says meters that are installed can extend beyond other equipment. Because of this most AHJ will allow an obstruction out to 8" but that is it. Think of it this way, for safety they don't want someone climbing on to a countertop or leaning over and falling into the live panel. So you must maintain that 30" width and 36" depth for safety.